# Unablex to load your default controller. Please make sure the controller specified in your Routes.php file is valid. CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

Este erro aparece ao dar Load no método Inicial:

> Unablex to load your default controller. Please make sure the
>   controller specified in your Routes.php file is valid.

E estou rodando o projeto `localhost` e funciona perfeitamente.
Mas no servidor, não funciona. Tentei alterar a versão do PHP para inferior ou superior, também não deu certo.

Estou roteando usando o third_party mx

Routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'inicial/inicial';
$route['404_override'] = 'inicial/erro';
```

Tentei substituir inicial/inicial por apenas inicial. Também não deu certo. O que estaria errado? Se localmente funciona perfeitamente.

Estou usando o CodeIgniter para renderizar o projeto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por mais incrível que pareça, consegui a solução da seguinte forma:
Acessando o arquivo ***system/core/codeigniter.php***

Procurei pelo erro mencionado:

> Unablex to load your default controller. Please make sure the
>   controller specified in your Routes.php file is valid.

e achei:

```
if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$RTR->fetch_directory().$RTR->fetch_class().'.php'))
{
    show_error('Unablex to load your default controller. Please make sure the controller specified in your Routes.php file is valid.');
}
```

Então, substitui por:

```
$arquivo = str_replace("..", "", APPPATH.$RTR->fetch_directory().$RTR->fetch_class().'.php');
if ( ! file_exists($arquivo))
{
    show_error('Unablex to load your default controller. Please make sure the controller specified in your Routes.php file is valid.');
}
```

Dessa maneira forcei com que o framework procure o arquivo da forma "correta", e neste caso funcionou.